# Pad array with transparent pixels in Matlab

Tags: matlab, transparency

I have written a piece of code in matlab that resizes images to a certain size (without distorting them), and applies padding when necessary.

However, the padding is black, and i would like it to be transparent. I don't know how to do this. This is the code i have:

```
% global variables
inputFolder = 'input/images/';
outputFolder = 'input/resized/';
extension = 'jpg';
x = 1000;
y = 1000;

% list all the files in the input folder
fileList = dir([inputFolder '*.' extension]); 

% loop through all the files in the input folder, resize, pad and save
for i=1:length(fileList)
    % get filename and load image
    fname = fileList(i).name;
    container = imread([inputFolder fname]);

    % calculate local variables
    containerY = size(container,1);
    containerX = size(container,2);
    containerProp = containerX / containerY;
    canvasProp = x / y;

    % determine proportions, apply padding and resize
    if containerProp < canvasProp
        container = imresize(container, [y NaN]);
        containerX = size(container,2);
        container = padarray(container, [0 floor((x - containerX)/2)], 0, 'pre');
        containerX = size(container,2);
        container = padarray(container, [0 (x - containerX)], 0, 'post');
    elseif containerProp == canvasProp
        container = imresize(container, [y x]);
    else
        container = imresize(container, [NaN x]);
        containerY = size(container,1);
        container = padarray(container, [floor((y - containerY)/2) 0], 0, 'pre');
        containerY = size(container,1);
        container = padarray(container, [(y - containerY) 0], 0, 'post');
    end

    % save resized image
    imwrite(container, [outputFolder fname]);
end
```

Does anyone know how to change the padding from black to transparent?

Comment: sorry, code highlighting for matlab code doesn't really work

Comment: The first problem is that jpeg does not have a transparency channel.

Comment: @user1071136, i know, but i'm going to save as a .png, so any transparent pixels i add will be saved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transparency is achieved through the use of an Alpha channel; your image is composed of pixels, each composed of a Red value, a Green value, a Blue value, and a transparency (=Alpha) value.

You can specify your alpha channel when writing a file,

```
imwrite(Image, 'filename.png', 'Alpha', AlphaMatrix)
```

where `Image` is a `R x C x 3` array, and `AlphaMatrix` is a `R x C` matrix. 
(`R` and `C` are the image dimensions)
`Image` contains RGB values, while `AlphaMatrix` contains the Alpha values.

Enough of explanations - here's an example. You need a `jpg` file; this will write
a `png` file with a gradient transparency. That is, it will be completely transparent
on the left, and completely opaque on the right.

```
I = imread('a.jpg');

imwrite(I, 'a.png', 'Alpha', ...
    repmat((1:size(I,2))/size(I,2), [size(I, 1) 1]));
```

In your case, you only have to fill the opaque parts with the value 1, and the transparent values with 0. Note the data-type of your array - if it is `uint8` or `uint16`, all values must be in the range `[0..255]`. If it is `double`, it should be in the range `[0..1]`.

One way to do so is to

1. After `imresize`, convert `container` to `double`: `container = double(container);`.
2. `padarray` with `NaN`: `padarray(container, [0 floor(...)], nan, 'pre');`
3. Fill an alpha channel with 0 wherever `container` has `NaN`, otherwise 1 :

   ```
   alpha = uint8(ones(size(container)));
   alpha(isnan(container)) = 0;
   ```
4. Fix `container` to be `uint8` and not contain `NaN`s:

   ```
    container(isnan(container(:,:,1))) = 0;
    container = uint8(container);
   ```

(hopefully somebody can come up with a prettier solution...)

Comment: +1 for listing all the gotchas - different behaviour of image functions when presented with `int` and `double` arguments, *wut*?